# Samsung 860 EVO not recognized as solid state drive

Tags: ssd

iMac 2019 running Mojave does not recognize Samsung 860 EVO as being a solid state drive. Drive is attached via Thunderbolt 3 and installed Ineo USB C enclosure. Disk utility info recognizes the drive as Samsung 860 EVO but indicates it is not a solid state drive.

Is this bug in OS are is there another explanation?

Comment: Does this cause you a problem, or are you merely curious?

Comment: There’s probably an issue with your enclosure.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I can not find a thunderbolt 3 enclosure made by Ineo that can hold a Samsung 860 EVO.

Comment: First of all, welcome on Ask Different. The description of your devices is a bit confusing. If your enclosure is a USB-C enclosure, then it is not using Thunderbolt3 but USB-C. It is confusing, plugs are the same shape, but protocol is different. 

- How is formatted your drive? I would recommend APFS which is a filesystem optimised for SSD.
- Could you provide a copy of the infos of the hard drive?
- If RW speeds are not impacted, I would say that it is not a big issue if it is not recognised as an SSD drive.

Comment: The Ineo enclosure that I am using in model C2580c. It is a USB3.1 Gen 2 (10Gbps) external enclosure with USB Type-C connector. I know that it is not a Thunderbolt 3 enclosure but USB C peripherals work when connected to a Thunderbolt 3 port. I have no problem with read/write speeds because the 10 Gbps capability of USB 3.1 Gen 2 exceeds the maximum of the 6 Gbps SATA interface.

Comment: The reason that I am asking about the drive not being recognized as solid state is that I want to understand if this will decrease the life of the drive. My internal SSD is recognized as a solid state drive and gets mounted with the "noatime" flag to reduce unnecessary writes when files are accessed. The Samsung EVO drive is not recognized as solid state and is not mounted with the "noatime" flag. I have an APFS partition on the EVO drive as well as a couple of Linux extfs partitions.